# How to change Localizable In StoryBoards Strings without restarting App Ios

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have a problem about localizable strings in ios application.I have two different files which names are storyboards.strings and localizable.strings. Some times I use for example ; "Name".localized() and I changed text without restarting app but for storyboards.strings I can not change without restarting app. I use for storyboards strings change this code it works but I have to restart app. Can anyone say to me why ? Thanks...

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["tr"], forKey: "AppleLanguages") 
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: You can use `NSLocalizedString("keyToLocalize",tableName: "tableNameAccordingToAppLanguage", comment: "")`

Comment: thnks for your answer but I wrote this code I get this error Nslocalizedstring... is unsed. I develop with swift 4 and Where am I supposed to write viewcontroller or appdelegate ?

Comment: You need change the localization on all your app, this is using the normal localization instead of Storyboard localization, you can define your localizable text in .strings files and change it in your app execution without restart the app

Comment: Okay I see because I didn't any solving this problem. I aldready use localized_swift library but I need change storyboards strings too .There are too many labels and button text but I guess , I have to label.text = "Hello".localized() . for every UI elements. Thnks bro

Comment: that is the way i know bro, sorry